# Silverlight tracing with AviCode

Tags: .net, silverlight, avicode

Does anybody know any how-to that shows tracing and monitoring Silverlight apps with AviCode? 
Or, another question - please advice a solution similar to AviCode that is able to gather events/performance statistics for distributed .NET apps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never met a solution that does Silverlight applications monitoring similar to AVIcode or other APM. Maybe there is something more like a tracing tool to use on your own machine, I didn't find one yet.
AppDynamics would be a good to solution to monitor distributed .NET apps performance and failures, it supports Java apps monitoring as well.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I'm just trying different Business Transaction Management solutions and will try AppDynamics as well.